React Native failing on M1 Mac
I am getting a number of different issues when trying to start a React Native project on my M1 Mac. I have tried different versions of Node, and React Native. After uninstalling and reinstalling I get the following. I have also reinstalled Cocoa Pods, changed targets in Xcode but cannot get the app to run

Generating Pods project

Command
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/pod install

Report

What did you do?
What did you expect to happen?
What happened instead?

Stack
   CocoaPods : 1.14.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [arm64-darwin23]
    RubyGems : 3.1.6
        Host : macOS 14.2.1 (23C71)
       Xcode : 15.3 (15E204a)
         Git : git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/

Plugins
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

Podfile
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip
platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!
# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled
linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end
target 'NewApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  target 'NewAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
  end
end

Error
LoadError - dlopen(/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib/nkf.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib/nkf.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib/nkf.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib/nkf.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib/nkf.bundle
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib/nkf.rb:5:in `require'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib/nkf.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib/kconv.rb:13:in `require'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib/kconv.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/CFPropertyList-3.0.7/lib/cfpropertylist/rbCFPropertyList.rb:3:in `require'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/CFPropertyList-3.0.7/lib/cfpropertylist/rbCFPropertyList.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/CFPropertyList-3.0.7/lib/cfpropertylist.rb:3:in `require'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/CFPropertyList-3.0.7/lib/cfpropertylist.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:25:in `require'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:25:in `read_from_path'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/xcode/xcframework.rb:41:in `initialize'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:518:in `new'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:518:in `load_xcframework'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:746:in `block (3 levels) in <class:PodTargetSettings>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:746:in `map'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:746:in `block (2 levels) in <class:PodTargetSettings>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:745:in `each'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:745:in `flat_map'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:745:in `block in <class:PodTargetSettings>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:120:in `block in define_build_settings_method'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:716:in `block in <class:PodTargetSettings>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:120:in `block in define_build_settings_method'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:727:in `block in <class:PodTargetSettings>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:120:in `block in define_build_settings_method'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:698:in `block (2 levels) in <class:PodTargetSettings>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:698:in `each'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:698:in `flat_map'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:698:in `block in <class:PodTargetSettings>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:120:in `block in define_build_settings_method'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:395:in `public_send'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:395:in `block in to_h'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:394:in `each'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:394:in `to_h'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:188:in `block in <class:BuildSettings>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:587:in `block in <class:PodTargetSettings>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:120:in `block in define_build_settings_method'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:204:in `save_as'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/target_installer_helper.rb:24:in `update_changed_file'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:644:in `block in create_xcconfig_file'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:642:in `each'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:642:in `create_xcconfig_file'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:71:in `block in install!'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:40:in `install!'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:115:in `block in install_pod_targets'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:112:in `map'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:112:in `install_pod_targets'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:32:in `block in install_all_pod_targets'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:31:in `install_all_pod_targets'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:19:in `generate!'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:320:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:315:in `create_and_save_projects'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in `generate_pods_project'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:183:in `integrate'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in `install!'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/user/Desktop/NewApp/NewApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/pod:23:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli.rb:476:in `exec'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:399:in `dispatch'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:476:in `start'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/libexec/bundle:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/libexec/bundle:34:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
[!] Oh no, an error occurred.
Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FUsers%2Fuser%2FDesktop%2FNewApp%2FNewApp%2Fvendor%2Fbundle%2Fruby%2F2.7.0%2Fgems%2Fnkf-0.2.0%2Flib%2Fnkf.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+tried%3A+%27%2FUsers%2Fuser%2FDesktop%2FNewApp%2FNewApp%2Fvendor%2Fbundle%2Fruby%2F2.7.0%2Fgems%2Fnkf-0.2.0%2Flib%2Fnkf.bundle%27+%28mach-o+file%2C+but+is+an+incompatible+architecture+%28have+%27x86_64%27%2C+need+%27arm64%27%29%29%2C+%27%2FSystem%2FVolumes%2FPreboot%2FCryptexes%2FOS%2FUsers%2Fuser%2FDesktop%2FNewApp%2FNewApp%2Fvendor%2Fbundle%2Fruby%2F2.7.0%2Fgems%2Fnkf-0.2.0%2Flib%2Fnkf.bundle%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2FUsers%2Fuser%2FDesktop%2FNewApp%2FNewApp%2Fvendor%2Fbundle%2Fruby%2F2.7.0%2Fgems%2Fnkf-0.2.0%2Flib%2Fnkf.bundle%27+%28mach-o+file%2C+but+is+an+incompatible+architecture+%28have+%27x86_64%27%2C+need+%27arm64%27%29%29+-+%2FUsers%2Fuser%2FDesktop%2FNewApp%2FNewApp%2Fvendor%2Fbundle%2Fruby%2F2.7.0%2Fgems%2Fnkf-0.2.0%2Flib%2Fnkf.bundle&type=Issues


Also experiencing this issue on a new 0.74 React Native project.

I eventually solved my problem by deleting Rosetta

I evenutally solved my issue by deleting Rosetta.
